# Extracting records of type "withdraw_rewards" from a multi-level data structure

Tags: javascript

Re-posting from StackOverflow as this is a place to review code that is already working.

I would like to know if there is a better way to deal with nested `forEach` when it comes to dealing with objects with properties that are nested arrays themselves.

My object (summarized):

```json
{
 ...,
 "tx_responses": [
   {
     ...
     "logs" : [
       {
         ...,
         "events": [
             {
                 "type": "coin_received",
                 "attributes": [
                     {
                         "key": "receiver",
                         "value": "somesome"
                     },
                     {
                         "key": "amount",
                         "value": "somesome"
                     }
                 ]
             },
             ...
             {
                 "type": "transfer",
                 "attributes": [
                     {
                         "key": "recipient",
                         "value": "somesome"
                     },
                     {
                         "key": "sender",
                         "value": "somesome"
                     },
                     {
                         "key": "amount",
                         "value": "somesome"
                     }
                 ]
             },
             {
                 "type": "withdraw_rewards",
                 "attributes": [
                     {
                         "key": "amount",
                         "value": "somesomesomehere"
                     },
                     {
                         "key": "validator",
                         "value": "somesome"
                     }
                 ]
             },
             ...
         ]
     }
 ],
...
```

I am essentially trying to extract all `{ key: 'amount', value: 'somesomesomehere' }` objects in the `attributes` array of the `"type" : "withdraw_rewards"` object in the `events` array.

Currently this is the code I wrote to carry out my task:

```
getWithdrawnAmounts: async(del_addr_) => {
    let withdrawnAmounts = [];
    const res = await axios.get("some_url_that_uses_del_addr_");
    res.data.tx_responses.forEach(txr => {
        txr.logs.forEach(log => {
            log.events.forEach(evnt => {
                if (evnt.type == "withdraw_rewards") {
                    evnt.attributes.forEach(attr => {
                        if (attr.key == "amount") {
                            withdrawnAmounts.push(attr);
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    });
    return withdrawnAmounts;
}
```

The code helps me to get what I need, but I was wondering if there is a better way to write my code so that I dont have to use so many nested `.forEach` methods. I was wondering if I should use `.flat()` or `.flatMap()` but I'm curious to know how would people approach this?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pipeline can be written simpler:

- replacing nested `.forEach` using `.flatMap`
- replacing conditionals inside `.forEach` using `.filter`

Also, instead of appending to `withdrawnAmounts` in the deepest `.forEach`,
you can make the pipeline return a filtered list.

```
return res.data.tx_responses
  .flatMap(txr => txr.logs)
  .flatMap(log => log.events)
  .filter(evnt => evnt.type === "withdraw_rewards")
  .flatMap(evnt => evnt.attributes)
  .filter(attr => attr.key === "amount");
```

Answer (score 0):

here is example if you want to use flatmap.

It's an improvement of original as i am using only 3 flatmaps and forEach loop.

```
        const logs = data.tx_responses.flatMap(item=>item.logs);
            const events = logs.flatMap(item=>item.events)
            const attributes = events.flatMap(item=> { 
            if(item.type == "withdraw_rewards") {
return item.attributes
}
            else{
 return null
}
            })
attributes.forEach(attr => {
                    if (attr.key == "amount") {
                        withdrawnAmounts.push(attr);
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].